# "python: not found" error when trying to install V8JS

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, v8js

I'm trying to install `V8JS` on my local machine (Windows OS) in `c:xampp\v` directory. I've used below commands in `Git`:

```
$ git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git 
$ export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
$ gclient
```

The result of last command (ran it several times):

```
Downloading CIPD client for windows-amd64 from https://chrome-infra-packages.ap
pspot.com/client?platform=windows-amd64&version=git_revision:db7a486094873e3944
b8e27ab5b23a3ae3c401e7...
Failed to download the file, check your network connection
At C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\cipd.ps1:116 char:10
+     throw <<<<  "Failed to download the file, check your network connection"
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Failed to downl...work connec
   tion:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Failed to download the file, check your network
   connection

Failed to bootstrap or update CIPD client
```

Then I tried:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/certik/python-2.7.git
$ fetch v8
```

And below came up:

```
/c/xampp/v/depot_tools/fetch: line 8: exec: python: not found
```

What's wrong and how could be resolved?

Edit: I've tried official Python but below error comes up:

```
v8 (ERROR)
----------------------------------------
[0:00:00] Started.
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\metrics.py", line 267, in print_notice_and_exit
    yield
  File "C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 3157, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 3143, in main
    return dispatcher.execute(OptionParser(), argv)
  File "C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\subcommand.py", line 252, in execute
    return command(parser, args[1:])
  File "C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 2700, in CMDsync
    ret = client.RunOnDeps('update', args)
  File "C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 1738, in RunOnDeps
    patch_refs=patch_refs, target_branches=target_branches)
  File "C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\gclient_utils.py", line 911, in flush
    reraise(e[0], e[1], e[2])
  File "C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\gclient_utils.py", line 988, in run
    self.item.run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 915, in run
    file_list)
  File "C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 133, in RunCommand
    return getattr(self, command)(options, args, file_list)
  File "C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 511, in update
    mirror = self._GetMirror(url, options, revision_ref)
  File "C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 951, in _GetMirror
    if not self.cache_dir:
  File "C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 219, in cache_dir
    return git_cache.Mirror.GetCachePath()
  File "C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\git_cache.py", line 301, in GetCachePath
    ['cache.cachepath']).strip()
  File "C:\xampp\v\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 216, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\xampp\v\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\xampp\v\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 644, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Running: 'C:\xampp\v\python\python.exe' 'C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\gclient.py' root
Running: 'C:\xampp\v\python\python.exe' 'C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\gclient.py' config --spec 'solutions = [
  {
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git",
    "managed": False,
    "name": "v8",
    "deps_file": "DEPS",
    "custom_deps": {},
  },
]
'
Running: 'C:\xampp\v\python\python.exe' 'C:\xampp\v\depot_tools\gclient.py' sync --with_branch_heads
Subprocess failed with return code 1.
```

Comment: What're you trying to download? V8JS is a PHP wrapper for V8, but you only talk about Python. Why use [an unofficial Python 2.7 mirror](https://github.com/certik/python-2.7.git) when there is the official repository and even official installers at [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2716/)? `fetch` requires Python; *exec: python: not found* means that Python is not installed. [The url](https://chrome-infra-packages.appspot.com/client?platform=windows-amd64&version=git_revision:db7a486094873e3944b8e27ab5b23a3ae3c401e7) works for me in browser, downloads `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @phd I've tried what you said and new error appeared. I've updated the question.